# Simple Java Calculator Logic

Tags: java

I'm new to programming and I was making a calculator with only 1 textfield.
I need a method which can recognize which string characters from these **(+ , - , * , /)**
to send the result to a variable and when i click the **=** button it shows the result.
I have tried to write something like that **(1+2)** and save it to variable then then when I try to press **=** button to settext the variable it shows a privilage error.

Here is the code

```
    JButton btnOne = new JButton("1");
    btnOne.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            sum+=1;
            txtoprtn.setText(txtoprtn.getText()+"1");

    JButton btnTwo = new JButton("2");
    btnTwo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            sum+=2;
            txtoprtn.setText(txtoprtn.getText()+"2");
        }
    });

    JButton btnAdd = new JButton("+");
    btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            txtoprtn.setText(txtoprtn.getText()+"+");

        }
    });

    JButton btnEqual = new JButton("=");
    btnEqual.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            x = Integer.parseInt(txtoprtn.getText());
            txtoprtn.setText(Integer.toString(x));
            }

        }
    );
```

and this is the error

```
    **Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1+2"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at com.jadv.day01.tasks.AdvCalc$11.actionPerformed(AdvCalc.java:140)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)**
```

any suggestions????

Comment: privilage error? If you see error problems, post the code and post the error message.

Comment: there is the code and the error

Comment: well, you are trying to use `Integer.parseInt` to turn a String `"1+2"` into an integer, with a NumberFormatException being the obvious result...

Comment: It's not a "privilage error" (never heard of that), but a NumberFormatException, and that's a **big** difference. You need to either parse through the String yourself, extracting the numbers and the operators -- not a completely trivial thing to do, or use a tool such as Rhino to do this for you.

Answer (score 4):

### First problem

When you try to just write a string statement of "1+2", what do you expect will happen? It can't simply just be evaluated like that. You would have to first use `Integer.parseInt()` to each of your # buttons after the number insertion is done(say, when you click the +/-///*, or =. That means the number is done and you'll get say 
`Integer.parseInt("123") instead of Integer.parseInt("1")+Integer.parseInt("2")+Integer.parseInt("3")`
What you're trying to do is parsing a + in the middle of the parse. Keep the integer parse to the numbers and the operators stored somewhere else(explained in second problem)

### Second problem

When you say "+", that doesn't parse into any operation. You would have to store the values into their individual variables and when clicked a + button, you would get a correct answer. If you want to do this without any external imports, then you would have to store the operations in a list and evaluate when = is clicked.

```
btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            operations.add("+");//operations is a list
        }
});
```

### Solving both problems at once using an import

If you want to evaluate using a package, then use this:

```
ScriptEngine evaluationMachine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
engine.eval(foo); //evaluates something like "2+1" into 3.
```

with the following imports:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
```

EDIT: By the way, though the second way is much faster, you should probably try and write it without external imports since you're new to programming. There will be inevitable situations where you're going to have to think about the problem.

Comment: very interesting solution using a script engine to parse a string expression. imho that's pretty neat!

Comment: @trooper thank you :) I just happened to have used it recently actually.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the exception is that you are trying to parse a String like `"1+2"` to an Integer in the line:

`x = Integer.parseInt(txtoprtn.getText());`

You should store the numbers somewhere else, i.e. in an ArrayList.